# Changing the Tcl shell picked up by Tcl.pm when new'ing a Tcl interpreter within Perl

Tags: perl, tcl

```
use Tcl;

$interp = Tcl->new;
```

Is how Im instantiating my Tcl interpreter within my Perl script.

The Tcl shell it uses/creates(im not sure what happens here) is different from the tclsh I would like to use.

I do not have access to the Perl build so im hoping there is another way.

Thanks!
Joe

Comment: What differences are you seeing? Perhaps the perl module is using an older version of tcl? Or perhaps you're seeing the difference between tclsh as invoked interactively and plain tcl when running a script?

Comment: Im seeing that tclsh allows me to use packages id like (i.e. package req of certain packages works), but the Perl instantiates some different Tcl...

Answer (score 0):

Ok it appears that a shell that works is being instantiated.  If I point the auto_path to the directory containing the packages that are in the 'lib' directory of the Tcl install then it all works.  Thanks to Stack Overflow for being my programming dummy...